# AssertionError while writhing unittesting

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have an AssertionError while writhing an unittesting function for my Flask view, I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\eind\Joy-1\webapp-joy\test.py", line 45, in test_article
self.assertIn(b"test", response.data)
AssertionError: b'test' not found in b'<!doctype html>\n\n404 Not Found\n

## Not Found

\n

The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

\n'

Here is my unnitesting function:

```
def test_article(self):
    tester = app.test_client(self)
    response = tester.get('/article/<int:id>')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
    self.assertIn(b"<title>test</title>", response.data)
```

the title tag in mijn html file:

```
<title>test</title>
```

I tried to change my html template but that did not much..

Comment: Hey, could you clarify what is the question and problem you would like people to help you with?

Comment: I got an assertionerror while writhing an unnitest function for my view in python.

Comment: A) traceback shows different assert than the code. B) Are you sure that you actually get a bytes and not a string back from the `tester.get()` C) Where are you populating `<int:id>` D) You could always print out the response.data *before* you do the assert so that you actually know what stuff you get in as a response so that You can verify that the tester returns what what you expect it to return..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, the traceback output:

`AssertionError: b'test' not found in b'<!doctype html>\n\n404 Not Found\n`

tells that the content you got (`b'<!doctype html>\n\n404 Not Found\n`) does not have the content you are looking for (`b'test'`).

Also, the traceback output does not reflect your test function implementation where you are looking for `b"<title>test</title>"` instead of just `b"test"`.

Have you checked [how to customize your 404 page in Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/quickstart/#redirects-and-errors)?